# Trying to use native iOS code for connecting to .NET web service

Tags: ios, web-services, nsurlconnection, afnetworking

I have just gone through a tutorial to connect to a .NET web service from iOS using the library AFNetworking (http://afnetworking.com/).  My code works fine, however, I am wondering how I can achieve the same functionality using native code (like NSURLConnection) that comes by default in iOS?

Here is my code below:

```
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.blah.com"];

    NSString *soapBody = @"<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"utf-8\"?><soap:Envelope xmlns:xsi=\"http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance\" xmlns:xsd=\"http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema\" xmlns:soap=\"http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/\"><soap:Body><Customers xmlns=\"http://tempuri.org/\" /></soap:Body></soap:Envelope>";


NSMutableURLRequest *request = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:url];

[request setHTTPBody:[soapBody dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];

[request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];

[request addValue:@"http://tempuri.org/Customers" forHTTPHeaderField:@"SOAPAction"];
[request addValue:@"text/xml; charset=utf-8" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];

AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation = [[AFHTTPRequestOperation alloc] initWithRequest:request];

[operation setCompletionBlockWithSuccess:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject) {

    NSLog(@"%@", [operation responseString]);

} failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {

    NSLog(@"failed");

}];

[operation start];
```

In particular, it is this block of code:

```
AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation = [[AFHTTPRequestOperation alloc] initWithRequest:request];

[operation setCompletionBlockWithSuccess:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject) {

    NSLog(@"%@", [operation responseString]);

} failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {

    NSLog(@"failed");

}];

[operation start];
```

that I would like to know how to replace, using NSURLConnection.

Thanks in advance to all who reply.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try something like this

```
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.blah.com"];

NSString *soapBody = @"<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"utf-8\"?><soap:Envelope xmlns:xsi=\"http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance\" xmlns:xsd=\"http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema\" xmlns:soap=\"http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/\"><soap:Body><Customers xmlns=\"http://tempuri.org/\" /></soap:Body></soap:Envelope>";

NSMutableURLRequest *request = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:url];

[request setHTTPBody:[soapBody dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];

[request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];

[request addValue:@"http://tempuri.org/Customers" forHTTPHeaderField:@"SOAPAction"];

[request addValue:@"text/xml; charset=utf-8" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];

// Convert your data and set your request's HTTPBody property
NSString *stringData = @"some data";
NSData *requestBodyData = [stringData dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
request.HTTPBody = requestBodyData;

// Create url connection and fire request
NSURLConnection *conn = [[NSURLConnection alloc] init];
(void)[conn initWithRequest:request delegate:self];
```

Use these delegate methods to get your response or handle error

```
 - (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveResponse:(NSURLResponse *)response {
     //create _responseData variable before only
    _responseData = [[NSMutableData alloc] init];
}

- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveData:(NSData *)data {

    [_responseData appendData:data];
}

- (NSCachedURLResponse *)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection
                  willCacheResponse:(NSCachedURLResponse*)cachedResponse {
    return nil;
}

- (void)connectionDidFinishLoading:(NSURLConnection *)connection {
    // The request is complete and data has been received
    // You can parse the stuff in your instance variable now

}

- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didFailWithError:(NSError *)error {
    // The request has failed for some reason!
    // Check the error var
}
```

If you want the request to be synchronous try this:

```
NSError * error = nil;

NSURLResposnse *response;

NSData * data = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:request
                                          returningResponse:&response
                                                    error:&error];

if (error == nil)
{
    // Parse data here
}
```